# Bad Request whenFromBody mvc core2.2 dosent work

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-core

fromBody does not work in Web  mvc Core 2.2 for Post
In Postman I am trying to post some data. I have made it as simple as possible;

> iam see error 400 Bad Request

```
  var UserVmodl =
          {
             In_User_Name:'',
             In_Family :$("#Family").val(),
             User_Name :$("#Name").val()
             In_National_Code :$("#National_Code").val(),
             In_Birth_Date_sh :$("#dateBirth_Date").val(),
              In_Email:$("#Email").val()
          }
  $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SaveUser", "PersonalInfo")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(UserVmodl ),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
             async: true,
            beforeSend: function (request) {
                sendRequestVerificationToken(request);
            },
            success: function (data) { localSuccess(data); onSuccessFunc(data); }
        });

[Route("PersonalInfo")]
  [Area("client")]
  public class PersonalInfoController : Controller
  {

   [HttpPost]
    [Route("save")]
    public  IActionResult SaveUser([FromBody] PersonalInfo UserVmodl)
    {
      //var Result= _IUserService.UpdateUser(UserVmodl);
      return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to send RequestVerificationToken from headers if you need yo add antiforgery validation.

```
 $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("SaveUser", "PersonalInfo")',
                type: 'POST',
                headers : {
                  RequestVerificationToken:
                      $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                },                   
                data: JSON.stringify(UserVmodl),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                async: true,
                success: function (data) { localSuccess(data); onSuccessFunc(data); }
            });
```

Remember to add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in your form.
Besides,you need to return a json result since your ajax needs a return type of json.